# Bootstrap modal not working properly - Laravel 5.6

Tags: laravel, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've been trying to incorporate a modal to popup when the user clicks a button. 
When the button is clicked the background color changes to how it will look if the modal was there, but that is all that happens.

The modal just isn't there.

All the necessary scripts and css have been linked in the master layout file and the file in which I want the modal extends the layout of the master file.

```
<div id="doctor-page" class="layer-stretch">

<div class="layer-wrapper text-center">



    <div class="row">

        @foreach($events = Event::orderby('id')->get() as $event) 

        <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4">



            <div class="theme-block">
                <div class="theme-block-picture doctor-picture-2">
                    <img src="{{asset('images/uploads/doctor-1.jpg')}}" alt="">
                </div>



                <div class="doctor-name doctor-name-2">
                    <h4 style = "background-color : black"><a>{{$event->Event_Name}}</a></h4>
                </div>
                <div class="theme-block-hidden">
                    <div class="doctor-name">
                        <h4 style = "background-color : black"><a>{{$event->Event_Name}}</a></h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="doctor-details">
                        <div class="doctor-specility">
                            <p style="font-size: 12px">

                              {{  $event->Event_Description }}

                            </p>

                                <button class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect button button-bordered-warning button-hover-transparent m-1" type = "button" data-toggle = "modal" data-target = "#sponsor-modal" style = "background-color : grey">
                                    Sponsors
                                </button>

                                <div id="sponsor-modal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">

                                    <div class="modal-dialog">


                                        <div class="modal-content">

                                             <div class="modal-header">

                                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>

                                                <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>

                                            </div>

                                            <div class="modal-body">

                                                <p>Some text in the modal.</p>

                                            </div>

                                            <div class="modal-footer">

                                               <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>

                                            </div>


                                        </div>

                                    </div>

                                </div>
```

I am using a combination of bootstrap and MDL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace that code with following :

```
<div id="doctor-page" class="layer-stretch">
    <div class="layer-wrapper text-center">
        <div class="row">

        @foreach($events = Event::orderby('id')->get() as $event) 


            <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4">
                <div class="theme-block">
                    <div class="theme-block-picture doctor-picture-2">
                        <img src="{{asset('images/uploads/doctor-1.jpg')}}" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="doctor-name doctor-name-2">
                        <h4 style = "background-color : black">
                            <a>{{$event->Event_Name}}</a>
                        </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="theme-block-hidden">
                        <div class="doctor-name">
                            <h4 style = "background-color : black">
                                <a>{{$event->Event_Name}}</a>
                            </h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="doctor-details">
                            <div class="doctor-specility">
                                <p style="font-size: 12px">

                                    {{  $event->Event_Description }}

                                </p>
                                <button class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect button button-bordered-warning button-hover-transparent m-1" type = "button" data-toggle = "modal" data-target = "#sponsor-modal" style = "background-color : grey">
                                    Sponsors
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>      
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        @endforeach
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="sponsor-modal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```